# How to fix “Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502(). Using Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vercel

An error occurred with this application.

This is an error with the application itself, not the platform.

502: BAD_GATEWAY
Code: NO_STATUS_CODE_FROM_LAMBDA
ID: iad1:wxl75-1560370905627-90a165b2829d

Answer (score 0):

Check https://vercel.com/knowledge/how-to-debug-a-502-error. A 502 error is always caused by a code problem that you need to look into.